# c++ array of uint8 buffers

Tags: c++, arrays, buffer

In C++, I have an uint8 buffer of the length [len]. When allocating a single buffer I do this:

```
uint8 *buffer= new uint8[len];
```

What's the syntax for allocating an array of such buffers? This gives me a syntax error:

```
uint8** buffers = new uint8[len]*[bufferCount];
```

Comment: `uint8* buffers[bufferCount]`, then make the pointers point to newed arrays. Or use a vector and save yourself a lot of future pain.

Comment: The proper syntax would be: `std::vector<std::basic_string<uint8>>(bufferCount);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin any reason for using `basic_string` rather than another `vector`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: At least in theory, the tighter requirements on `basic_string` (e.g., elements can't throw when copied) allow slightly better optimization. Whether that really works in practice may be open to more question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you initialize a 2d array is as follows:

```
uint8** buffers = new uint8*[bufferCount];
for (int i = 0; i < bufferCount; i++)
    buffers[i] = new uint8[len];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>

using byte_vector = std::vector<uint8_t>;
using byte_vector_vector = std::vector<byte_vector>;


// example of a 1-dimension vector
auto v1 = byte_vector(len, inital_value);

// example of a [2, len] vector
auto v_of_v = byte_vector_vector { 
  byte_vector(len, initial_value),
  byte_vector(len, initial_value)
};

// print the uint8 at (0,1)
std::cout << v_ov_v[0][1] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> What's the syntax for allocating an array of such buffers?

You can use:

```
uint8** buffers = new uint8*[bufferCount];
```

However, use this only if `std::vector` is absolutely not an option for some reason.